# QGIS Function editor calculate area after transform

Tags: qgis

In the QGIS function editor, it is possible to transform geometry using transform(geometry,'EPSG:xxx','EPSG:yyy') - however there isn't an area() function to recalculate the area of this.

The reason I am looking to do this is to have area calculated when a map is produced (labelled and as a virtual field in the attribute table); rather than store the area within the database as it is likely to change frequently as users modify the polygons?

Comment: Can't you just use `$area` in your virtual field?

Comment: My data is in geographic coordinates, so I need it in square meters hence the transform.

Comment: That's an interesting question. I don't know if you can calculate the area without first transforming your layer to a projected coordinates system.

Comment: I'll see if I can use psycopg2 to get the value from my database using python instead of the editor. I can imagine that slowing things down a fair bit the more polygons there is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are aiming is a quite nice outcome about being able to transform the geometry. You can do it using an expression but you will need an extra plugin.

1. Install [reffunctions plugin](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/refFunctions/)
2. Then use the following expression:

   WKTarea(geomToWKT( transform(  $geometry , 'EPSG:xxxx', 'EPSG:yyyy')))

**UPDATE**

Transforming the geometry to WKT and then using an external plugin to solve the problem was bugging me. So I came up with a very simple better (I think) solution.

All that was needed was to add the following function to the function editor:

```
@qgsfunction(args="auto", group='Custom')
def area(geometry, feature, parent):
    return geometry.area()
```

The basic usage is:

```
area($geometry)
```

And the on-the-fly area calculation expression became:

```
area(transform(  $geometry , 'EPSG:xxxx', 'EPSG:yyyy'))
```

Comment: Thank you for mentioning this very useful plugin. It's simpler than my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with PostGIS as back-end, you could create a new column `area_auto` and create a trigger to keep it up-to-date with your features' areas.

First add a column to your table (here table=`poly_area`, new column=`area_auto`)

```
ALTER TABLE poly_area ADD COLUMN area_auto double precision;
```

Then populate the existing polygons with their areas:

```
UPDATE poly_area SET area_auto = ST_Area(geom::geography);
```

(assuming geom is in EPSG:4326, it must be cast to [geography](http://postgis.net/docs/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html#PostGIS_Geography_AdvancedFAQ)).

Then create a function to update column `area_auto`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_polygon_area_auto()   
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
    NEW.area_auto = ST_Area(NEW.geom::geography);
    RETURN NEW; 
END;
$$ language 'plpgsql';
```

Finally, create a trigger to automatically update `area_auto`:

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_area_auto
    BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
    ON public.poly_area
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE public.update_polygon_area_auto();
```

Now `area_auto`is automatically updated (in square meters) when you commit your changes in QGIS. You can label your features with it, and it's available in the attribute table.

[image: Automatic area calculation]