# Calculate area of geometry derived from current feature in QGIS 2.8

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, geometry, area

I'm trying to create a new field defined as the area of the convex hull of the current feature, in the Field Calculator in QGIS 2.8.

Calculating the area of the current feature is easy ($area), and calculating the convex hull of the current feature is easy (convexHull($geometry)), but I can't find any way to calculate the area of *that* resulting geometry (as opposed to the geometry of the current feature).

I think I need to be able to either:

- Apply an area calculation to that convex hull geometry in the Field Calculator -- this is what I'd prefer; or
- Write a custom function -- there appears to be a free-standing area function in the Function Editor, but I can't figure out how to get a simple custom function defined and called properly; shouldn't need any arguments, as it's just the area of the convex hull of the current geometry; or
- Create a new layer from an interim attribute that just contains the geometry of the convex hull -- then I could calculate the areas of *those* features in the new layer

Any suggestions on any of these approaches?

Comment: Haven't used this before but how about `area(convex_hull($geometry))` where `area` returns the area of geometry polygon object, in this case, the convex polygon?

Comment: Joseph is spot on

Comment: Exactly! That was my first thought. Seems like that should obviously work, but the Output preview says that the "Expression is invalid" with a "Parser Error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting $end".

Comment: convexHull($geometry) works and returns a geometry (the function is convexHull vs. convex_hull), but area(convexHull($geometry)) gives the error. Seems no obvious way to operate on the resulting geometry vs. the geometry of the current feature.

Comment: I've almost got the second approach, a custom function, working.

I created this little script in the Function Editor:

`from qgis.core import *

@qgsfunction(args=0, group='Custom')
def AreaOfConvexHull(value1, feature, parent):

    return QgsGeometry.area(QgsGeometry.convexHull(feature.geometry()))`

In the Output preview, it displays good looking result (vs. an error).

However, when I use the function to create a new attribute, I get a popup with the msg:

"QgqGeometry.convexHull(): first argument of unbound method must have type 'QgsGeometry'.

What am I doing wrong? So close ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UPDATE in this [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/150759/qgis-function-editor-calculate-area-after-transform) explains BOTH how to write the kind of custom function I was trying to write AND the specific function I needed. With this custom `area` function, the expression I need becomes simply `area(convexHull($geometry))`.