# How to create a convex hull using QGIS Geometry Generator?

Tags: qgis, convex-hull, geometry-generator

**Background:**

At 3.14.16, I'm trying to learn a little more about Geometry Generator, in this case *convex hull*.  I created a simple test point layer with six points.  I then used Geometry Generator with the expression **convex_hull($geometry)**, expecting an outline hull to display.  However, none appeared, as shown in the screenshot below.  Only the original points appear.

In my search for a solution, I came across [this SE GIS post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/182819/calculate-area-of-geometry-derived-from-current-feature-in-qgis-2-8), where  **convexHull($geometry)** was successfully used.  Unfortunately, that expression did not result in a outline for my points.

**Question:**

How do I display a convex hull around a point layer using Geometry Generator?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to select Polygon/ MultiPolygon geometry type for the geometry generator symbol layer, and add the `collect` function to your expression:

```
convex_hull(collect($geometry))
```

[image]

**Update August 2023:**

the `$geometry` function is now deprecated in favor of the `@geometry` variable.

So:

```
convex_hull(collect(@geometry))
```

Comment: FYI, now, `$geometry` is deprecated. You should switch to `@geometry` instead

Comment: @etrimaille, thanks for the reminder- answer updated.

Answer (score 2):

The correct answer is the one accepted.

Just adding another one if you are looking to do it with a common attribute :

```
convex_hull(collect (@geometry, group_by:="name_of_attribute"))
```

[image: convex hull with a common attribute]

A mix between [Geometry generator - classify objects in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/447136/geometry-generator-classify-objects-in-qgis) and the accepted answer here

Just to share, it took me some time to see we could give a group by in the `collect` expression.