# Geometry generator - classify objects in QGIS

Tags: qgis, classification, dissolve, geometry-generator

How can I display objects classified/dissolved by a specific attribute (f.e. dissolving polygons by state in the attributes), by using the Gemoetry Generator?

| FID | name | state |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Peter | BB |
| 2 | Ann | MV |
| 3 | Frank | BB |
| 4 | Günni | BE |

Comment: Please [edit] your post and clarify your question, maybe adding a clear example could help people to find a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To dissolve features based on a common attribute value with geometry generator, use this expression, here based on the attribute `name`:

```
buffer (collect ($geometry, group_by:="name"),0)
```

*Blue initial polygons dissolved to new polygon (outlined in red), based on common `NAME` attribute:*
[image]