# Creating convex_hull clusters from hierarchical nearest distances network percentiles in QGIS

Tags: qgis, geometry-generator

I work with a point layer in which I have calculated two fields:

`"LONGCLOSE"` = closest distances to each point I use the following function

Computed with this expression:

```
array_sum (array_foreach(
    overlay_nearest(@layer, $geometry,limit:=3),
    length (make_line ( $geometry, @element))
        )
    )
```

`"CENTILES"` = classifying percentiles

Computed with this expression:

```
with_variable(
'percentile',
array_find(array_agg("LONGCLOSE",order_by:="LONGCLOSE"),"LONGCLOSE") / array_length(array_agg("LONGCLOSE")),
    
    CASE
    WHEN @percentile < 0.25 THEN 1
    WHEN @percentile < 0.50 THEN 2
    WHEN @percentile < 0.75 THEN 3
    WHEN @percentile < 0.90 THEN 4
    WHEN @percentile <= 1 THEN 5
    ELSE 'Undefined'
    END
)
```

The layer thematized by categories shows the points with less distance (density zones) in dark color:

[image]

With the next expression I get to connect with a line the points from highest to lowest percentile:

```
with_variable(
    'curr',
    CENTILES,
    make_line (
        $geometry, 
        eval(
            'overlay_nearest(
                ''POINTSCONVEX2'',
                $geometry,
                filter:=CENTILES+1='  || @curr  || 
            ')'
        )[0]
    )
)
```

[image]

From this initial approach, and from this hierarchical network that is created, my goal is to reveal the clusters that define the convex polygon of each network. I show what I want to explain with a hand-made image:

[image]

The idea behind my question is, through "LONGCLOSE" and "CENTILES" fields calculation, and through an expression for Geometry Generator, to get an alternative representation of pseudo clusters.

Comment: cf. https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/465071/156742

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I don't think it solves my goal. It is a bit more complex than using the `group_by`. Anyway thanks, and I'm still looking for a solution